# Expected LP_LP_c_longlong instance instead of pointer to LP_c_longlong

Tags: python, c, interop, marshalling, ctypes

I have implemented a Python-C interop module using `ctypes`. Below are the relevant fragments:

```
# PQACORE_API void* PqaEngine_Compact(void *pvEngine, int64_t *pnQuestions, int64_t const ** const ppOldQuestions,
#   int64_t *pnTargets, int64_t const ** const ppOldTargets);
pqa_core.PqaEngine_Compact.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
pqa_core.PqaEngine_Compact.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,
   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)),
   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)))
```

However, I am getting an exception in the following code, line 707 is marked:

```
def compact(self) -> Tuple[List[int], List[int]]:
    n_questions = ctypes.c_int64()
    n_targets = ctypes.c_int64()
    p_questions = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)()
    p_targets = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)()
    c_err = ctypes.c_void_p()
    c_err.value = pqa_core.PqaEngine_Compact(self.c_engine, ctypes.byref(n_questions), ctypes.byref(p_questions),
         ctypes.byref(n_targets), ctypes.byref(p_targets)) # line 707
```

The exception says the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Servers\Web\Django\probqa.com-site\src\PqaWeb\pqawV1\admin_actions.py", line 146, in use_existing_engine
self.engine.compact()
File "D:\Servers\Web\Django\probqa.com-site\src\PqaWeb\ProbQAInterop\ProbQA.py", line 707, in compact
ctypes.byref(n_targets), ctypes.byref(p_targets))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_c_longlong instance instead of pointer to LP_c_longlong
```

The exception is thrown when the program runs under Apache/2.4.37 (Win64).

The code in C/C++ is correct. It's the Python code that needs to be fixed, so to correspond to the C API.

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: I created a dummy DLL with your C signature and did not get the error.  Everything looks correct.  Make a [mcve]?

Comment: @MarkTolonen, thanks for trying and confirming that the current code is correct. The problem seems intermittent, and it got fixed after restarting Apache a few times. Can it be some bug in Python/ctypes?